# Didn't show counter number and counter bar in php voting system

Tags: php

here is my index.html:

```
<div style="margin:50px">
    <a href="#" class="like" id="1" name="up"><img src="likebig.png" alt="Like" border="0"></a>
    <a href="#" class="like" id="1" name="down"><img src="dislike.png" alt="dislike" border="0"></a>
    <div id="votebox">
        <span id='close'><a href="#" class="close" title="Close This">X</a></span>
        <div style="height:13px">
            <div id="flash">Loading........</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and rating.php:

```
include("db.php");
if($_POST['id'] > 0 && $_POST['name']> 0){
    $id=mysql_escape_String($_POST['id']);
    $name=mysql_escape_String($_POST['name']);

    mysql_query("update messages set $name=$name+1 where id='$id'");
    $result=mysql_query("select up,down from messages where id='$id'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $up_value=$row['up'];
    $down_value=$row['down'];
    $total=$up_value+$down_value;
    $up_per=($up_value*100)/$total;
    $down_per=($down_value*100)/$total;
?>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <b>Ratings for this blog</b> ( <?php echo $total; ?> total)
    </div>
    <table width="700px">
        <tr>
            <td width="30px">
                <img src="likeup.png">
            </td>
            <td width="60px"><?php echo $up_value; ?></td>
            <td width="600px"><div id="greebar" style="width:<?php echo $up_per; ?>%"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30px">
                <img src="likedown.png">
            </td>
            <td width="60px"><?php echo $down_value; ?></td>
            <td width="600px"><div id="redbar" style="width:<?php echo $down_per; ?>%"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}
```

and this is ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".like").click( function() {
            var id=$(this).attr("id");
            var name=$(this).attr("name");
            var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name='+ name;
            $("#votebox").slideDown("slow");

            $("#flash").fadeIn("slow");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "rating.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#content").html(html);
                } 
            });
        });

        $(".close").click(function() {
            $("#votebox").slideUp("slow");
        });

    });
</script>
```

I have tried for a long time, still i can't able to fix error.

It didn't show counter number and count-bar after clicking the like or unlike button.

Now it shows like this http://s15.postimg.org/e6pvjkrej/Untitled_1.png.

I need like this: http://s15.postimg.org/qmmldbkqj/Untitled_2.png

May how can i fix this? can anyone help me to fix this ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was not only the "greenbar" and "redbar". The problem was also the output. You need to echo all the html so that ajax could get the html.

```html
<?php
    include("db.php");
    if($_POST['id'] > 0 && $_POST['name']> 0){
        $id=mysql_escape_String($_POST['id']);
        $name=mysql_escape_String($_POST['name']);
    
        mysql_query("update messages set $name='".$name+1."' where id='".$id."'");
        $result=mysql_query("select up,down from messages where id='".$id."'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    
        $up_value=$row['up'];
        $down_value=$row['down'];
        $total=$up_value+$down_value;
        $up_per=($up_value*100)/$total;
        $down_per=($down_value*100)/$total;
    //HTML Output for AJAX Calls
      echo  "<div style='margin-bottom:10px'>
            <b>Ratings for this blog</b> (". $total ." total)
        </div>
        <table width='700px'>
            <tr>
                <td width='30px'>
                    <img src='likeup.png'>
                </td>
                <td width='60px'>". $up_value ."</td>
                <td width='600px'><div id='greebar' style='width:'". $up_per ."%'></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='30px'>
                    <img src='likedown.png'>
                </td>
                <td width='60px'>".$down_value."</td>
                <td width='600px'><div id='redbar' style='width:'". $down_per ."%'></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
        }
    ?>
```

Here's the code for HTML Output from the tutorial for reference:

```
echo '<b>Ratings for this blog</b> ( '.$total.' total)
Like :'.$up_value.'
<div id="greebar" style="width:'.$up_per.'%"></div>
Dislike:'.$down_value.'
<div id="redbar" style="width:'.$down_per.'%"></div>';
```

[link](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/07/youtube-like-rating-jquery-and-ajax.html)

Comment: i don't know why but anyway i will put the code from the tutorial itself

Comment: I think that the variables "down_per" and "up_per" are getting out of scope. try echoing those two vars and tell me the output

Comment: look at the revised code. As i see you're trying to get the data from the db using an ajax call to the rating.php so, here's the changed rating.php to support such calls

Comment: in this line, showed parse error:       echo  '<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <b>Ratings for this blog</b> ('. $total; .' total)
        </div>

Comment: oops, my bad...remove the semicolons from everything inside the echo read the redone rating.php

Comment: i reworked the code but if it doesn't work then i would bet there's something wrong with the included db.php file. Can you add a snippet of that file with the user details censored out?